# Is there a better alternative for the Jaccard index to obtain the relationship between binary indices?

Tags: binary-data, similarities, association-measure, jaccard-similarity

I currently have data from $n$ sources. Each source sends a binary signal each minute. I have a register of $p$ minutes.

I have used Python to calculate the [Jaccard indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) of each signal as

```
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_score

#...

for i in range(num_bin_sensors):
        for j in range(nnum_bin_sensorss):
            jaccard=jaccard_score(data_state.iloc[i], data_state.iloc[j])
            jaccard_scores_matrix[i, j]=jaccard

for i in range(num_bin_sensors):
        transformed_data = [1 if x == 0 else 0 for x in data_state.iloc[i]]
        for j in range(num_bin_sensors):
            jaccard=jaccard_score(transformed_data, data_state.iloc[j])
            jaccard_scores_matrix_negative[i, j]=jaccard
```

This code allows the calculation of a positive index in the first nested loops to check if there is "positive correlation" and a negative index in the second nested loops to indicate if there is "negative correlation". My goal with this is to obtain an equivalent for the [Pearson correlation coefficien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient)t for binary data.

So I was wondering if there is a better alternative that what I am doing.

Comment: The word _correlation_ is best avoided here. At most you're measuring overlap between sets and there is in particular no equivalent of negative correlation. The alternatives are often reviewed in works on cluster analysis. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1469-185X.1982.tb00376.x is one detailed review.

Comment: I've edited tags accordingly.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for your answer. I would be thankful if you were more speciffic. I cannot access the article. I however, think that I can do dbscan clustering with jaccard distance and a small epsilon.

Comment: I don't know what you find vague in my comment. Jaccard is bounded by 0 and 1 in which 0 means no elements in common between two sets and 1 means all elements in common. There is no analogue of negative correlation, or even association.

Comment: Well. I was hoping to be told of other metrics which were able to be used as a measurement of the similarity between the variables. I am currently trying to implement the cosine similarity.

Comment: Indeed, and sorry to disappoint, but I was just giving a comment and not trying a full answer. To me there is little point in trying to summarize a topic already discussed at length in the literature. More crucially, I don't see that your question gives any flavour either of how your data behave or of your precise goals. For example, in some contexts it is important to count elements in neither of two sets, which Jaccard does not try to do. If that's true for your project, Jaccard won't work well.